# Gradle: set property in project dependency

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management

I am looking for the solution of setting properties of project dependencies with gradle with configuration closures. I already had the solution but my computer crashed and I can't remember how I did this.

I have the following Android project structure:

```
/
-lib/
  - build.gradle
-app/
  - build.gradle
- build.gradle
```

In the `lib:build.gradle` I have a `ext` closure:

```
ext {
    username = null
    password = null
    serverUrl = 'example.com'
}
```

In the `app:build.gradle` I add the lib as a project dependency:

```
compile project(':lib')
```

In some way, I achieved to set the `ext` properties with a statement like

```
compile project(path: ':lib', configClosure: { ext.username='test' })
```

Unfortunately, this isn't the correct statement. But what was it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to pass parameters with it's names. Just do it this way:

```
compile project(':lib', { ext.username='test' })
```

And the second is, you don't need to add a property in the `lib:build.gradle` if you want to set it from outside. So you have to delete this part of your build script:

```
ext {
    username = null
}
```

if you want to set `username` from outside. Otherwise the value from outside will be set with the null value.

And if you wich to have default value, then you have to make a `gradle.properties` file in your `:lib` project and set this values in this properties file as:

```
username=test
```